# If Fenrir Greyback didn't have a Dark Mark, how could he get through a barrier that required a Dark Mark to pass through it?

Tags: harry-potter

Just like the question indicates — **if Fenrir Greyback didn't have a Dark Mark, how could he get through a barrier that required a Dark Mark to pass through it?**

We see in *HBP* that the barrier that separated the Astronomy tower (where Dumbledore was to be murdered) and the battle required a Dark Mark to pass through.

> "[...] and I'll bet you had to have a Dark Mark to get through that barrier [...]" -*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, Chapter 29, *The Phoenix Lament*, pg. 621

We also know that Fenrir Greyback was present at the murder of Dumbledore.

> "Is that you, Fenrir?" asked Dumbledore.
>
> "That's right," rasped the other. -*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, Chapter 27, *The Lightning-Struck Tower*, pg. 593

But we learn in *DH* that Greyback does not have the Dark Mark.

> "I haven't got — they say he's using the Malfoys' place as a base. We'll take the boy there."
>
> Harry thought he knew why Greyback was not calling Voldemort. The werewolf might be allowed to wear Death Eater robes when they wanted to use him, but only Voldemort's inner circle were branded with the Dark Mark: Greyback had not been granted this highest honor. -*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, Chapter 23, *Malfoy Manor*

So, **if Greyback didn't have a Dark Mark, how could he get through a barrier that required a Dark Mark to pass through it?**

Comment: Reading the quotes you provided, i'm not seeing anything that says Greyback did get through a barrier that requires a Dark Mark.  The first quote says "I'll bet" which means the person saying it doesn't actually know that the barrier  required a Dark Mark to get through.

Comment: @shufly - Also, Fenrir is a known presence. Making a magical exception for him would presumably be well within the capacity of whoever set the barrier

Comment: Second thing from quotes is choronology - just because there was a barrier at one point, doesn't mean there was a barrier up at the time that Fenrir was involved. It could have been dropped as no-longer-necessary, or taken down/countered.

Comment: the death eaters could have first went up the stairs and then make the barrier

Comment: Please include the source for the last quote. You got the first two, but forgot the last one.

Comment: @FreeMan Oh, I forgot! Thanks for reminding me :D

Comment: No worries, that's what the [peanut gallery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peanut_gallery) is here for!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many possibilities here :

1 . The Barrier doesn't need a dark mark to go through. Perhaps anyone who owes his allegiance to the Dark Lord can cross the barrier (eg werewolves, giants, etc.). Of course this is purely speculation.

2 . The Barrier had an exception to Fenrir. The person who cast the barrier made an exception to Fenrir. This is possible only if we assume that the barrier needs a Dark Mark to be crossed. The person who cast it might have known that Fenrir wouldn't be able to cross it so they made an exception for him.

3 . The barrier wasn't there at the time Fenrir went past. Fenrir came with the Death Eaters. And the spell may have been cast after all the death eaters had passed. Similarly, when they were coming down, the death eaters removed the barrier, to let Fenrir through.

4 . You can cross the barrier if you are with someone who has a dark mark (similar to side along apparition). So, if you are with someone who has a Dark Mark you can cross the barrier. Obviously, Fenrir and his pals crossed the barrier at thee same time.

Comment: Or you can pass through if you want to kill Dumbledore. That should rule out anyone on the 'right' side. Magic has a lot to do with intent.

Comment: The Barrier was designed to be ADA compliant and therefore had an exception for service dogs.

Comment: There is evidence in Crimes of Grindelwald that magical barriers exist that can only be (safely) crossed by people loyal to the wizard who conjured them.

Comment: @A.Darwin: Ugh... That sort of magic basically makes traitors an impossibility. "Oh, hey, loyal henchman <Insert Name>, leave your wand over there, then come on through this barrier. Wait, you can't get through? Definitely going to assume the magic is broken rather than that you've been in deep cover working for my enemies." Even mind-reading is less disruptive to reasonable plots, at least there you can claim it can only read surface thoughts, or deep scans cause brain damage so innocent people resist them. Magic that *proves* loyalty (more generally, intent) is the death of intrigue.